# What material should be used in making a heat resistant lens?

Tags: lens

What kind of lens (what material(s) should it be made of) can withstand very extreme temperature changes?

I'm trying to use a camera in temperature ranges of approximatly 60 to 400 degrees Fahrenheit

What should the lens be made out of?

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate post of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17885/ (which is, I think, a better place for it — you're already getting good answers!)

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to know if anyone here knew of something I could buy as opposed to something that would work, if it existed.  Thanks though.

Comment: There's a big difference between temperatures and temperature changes. Some materials that can withstand high temperatures can not withstand rapid temperature changes because of the stresses those changes produce especially in interfaces between parts and materials. Other materials/interfaces can withstand those stresses but can't survive long at high temperatures.

Comment: @jwenting Thanks, but do you have any suggestions as to what type of lens I could purchase?

Comment: I've never investigated lenses for extreme conditions. But my guess is you're probably going to end up with specialised cameras for extreme environments rather than lenses that slot onto your SLR (which itself isn't able to survive those environments of course). Try finding companies selling sensors to the (petro)chemical industry, they may have things of interest to you. And don't forget the heat resistant cables to connect that camera to a recording device (probably a laptop).

Comment: If I remove the case and everything plastic from the SLR, would the camera work?  (I'd also be removing the lcd...  I just need the most basic digital camera...)

Comment: As jwenting said, you're well into specialized camera territory. Most specifications that I see don't recommend using a camera in temperatures above 105F or so.  Removing plastic won't really be a help, since the battery, and probably the sensor too, is likely much more sensitive to heat than the plastic case.

Comment: @AndrewStevens thanks, if you or mattdm or anyone else wants to post something as an answer... I have to accept something...

Comment: @wizlog: What exactly do you need such a lens for? How exactly will you be using it? Do you intend to fabricate it on your own, or are you hoping to buy something off the shelf? There are few optically useful refractive materials that can withstand rapidly changing temperatures, and you also have to think about the temperature range of the material used to mount the lens elements can handle.

Comment: Needs much more clarification of the situation

Comment: @RobinBrown Not sure it does.  I found a company that makes lenses out of Pyrex (borosilicate glass).

Comment: What I mean is that you're asking a very specific question whereas filling in the background and asking a more general question would get you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of the big brand commercial DSLRs or compact cameras will withstand a temperature of 400 fahrenheit, they'd all be junk if exposed for more than a moment. 100 F or so is the practical limit.

Which means that you'll have to start looking for specialist industrial applications like this quick search result: http://www.lenoxinst.com/Pultz_High-Temp_Cameras.html

Having read your question on Physics I think a practical answer might be to remove or borrow an untinted glass oven door from an old oven, place it in front of your fire and photograph through it with a big macro lens. That's assuming you want to take pictures of a fireplace up close of course. If you want to take macro pictures of burning coal/logs then the link above is a better idea.

Comment: Those cameras require cooling however I like your idea to using old glass from an oven.